# Navbar (bootstrap) styling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following navbar code:-

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container">
  <ul class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <% if current_user %>
      <li class="nav-item pull-right add-space">Signed in as  <%= current_user.name %> - <%= image_tag @auth['info']['image'],
        width: '32', height: '32', class: 'nav-logo' %></li>
      <li class="nav-item pull-right add-space"><%= link_to "Sign out    ", '/sign_out', method: :delete, class: 'nav-link' %></li>
    <% else %>
      <li class="nav-item pull-right add-space"><%= link_to image_tag("GitHub-Mark-Light-32px.png"), "auth/github", class: "nav-link"%></li>
      <li class="nav-item pull-right add-space"><%= link_to image_tag("twitter-32-1.png"), "auth/twitter", class: "nav-link" %></li>
      <li class="nav-item pull-right add-space"><%= link_to image_tag("facebook-2-32.png"), "auth/facebook", class: "nav-link" %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
        </form>
      </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
```

And I am confused about the styling using the bootstrap CSS classes. You will see I have used the navbar-form navbar-left class on the UL tag as without this the images I have in the LI tags are top aligned and look out of place. There is an unintended consequence of this though in that my 'Sign out' link is now aligned to the top and its blue (instead of white and most likely because of the nav-link class) and the 'Signed in as 'text is almost unreadable as it's sort of greyed out.

I ams sure there is a combination of styles that should work but having tried quite a few I was wondering whether anyone could help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `nab-form` or `nav-item` in the [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

`ul` should have `nav navbar-nav` class, `li` should not have one.

You could start your menu with the [Navbar template for Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/)

Comment: Thank you - I have reworked now and moved the sign out to a button and this works fine. Still not got the 'Signed in as' text readable and I could do with a bot of spacing around the icon links. Also the carousel text slides off the page when resizing the screen.

Comment: Okeyy could you provides us a code snippet ? (there is one integrate in Stackoverflow)

It would be easy form us to see the result.

Comment: Hi Qanta - I thought I added this yesterday as an answer to my own question but it appears not. I haven't got access to the source at present but will add later. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`nav-item` is for the Bootstrap 4 navbar, so make sure you're pointing to the 4.x version.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for the navbar and the main issue is the spacing on the icons looks a bit odd and the 'Signed in as' text is unreadable+

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Static navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <% if current_user %>
                <li class="nav-link pull-right add-space">Signed in as  <%= current_user.name %> - <%= image_tag @auth['info']['image'],
  width: '32', height: '32', class: 'nav-logo' %></li>
                <%else%>
                <%end%>
            </ul>
              <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <% if current_user %>
                    <li class="nav-item pull-right add-space"><%= link_to "Sign out    ", '/sign_out', method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-success' %></li>
                  <% else %>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
                  <li class="nav-item pull-right add-space"><%= link_to image_tag("GitHub-Mark-Light-32px.png"), "auth/github", class: "nav-link"%></li>
                  <li class="nav-item pull-right add-space"><%= link_to image_tag("twitter-32-1.png"), "auth/twitter", class: "nav-link" %></li>
                  <li class="nav-item pull-right add-space"><%= link_to image_tag("facebook-2-32.png"), "auth/facebook", class: "nav-link" %></li>
                          <%end%>
                </form>
              </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
          <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible"><%= value %></div>
        <% end %>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <% if current_user %>
        <div class="text-center">
          <h1>Welcome, you are logged in with <strong><%= @auth['provider'].capitalize %></strong></h1>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```